# Getting a error when using If / Else if on string in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I am trying to convert the string characters for months into numerical representations. As you can see from the code I am attempting to convert the numbers into characters so that I am not placing a number where a character string used to be. But I am still getting the error below. I am using na.omit so there should be no NA's in the dataset.

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(8L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 8L, 2L,  :
invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Here is the code:

```
forestfires <- read.csv('forestfires.csv')

forestfireDf <- data.frame(cbind(forestfires))

forestfireDf <- na.omit(forestfireDf)

for (i in length(forestfireDf)) {
  if (forestfireDf$month[i] == 'jan') {
    forestfireDf$month[i] = as.character(1)
       } else if (forestfireDf$month[i] == 'feb') {
    forestfireDf$month[i] = as.character(2)
       } else if (forestfireDf$month[i] == 'mar') {
    forestfireDf$month[i] = as.character(3)
       } else if (forestfireDf$month[i] == 'apr') {
    forestfireDf$month[i] = as.character(4)
       } else if (forestfireDf$month[i] == 'may') {
    forestfireDf$month[i] = as.character(5)
       } else if (forestfireDf$month[i] == 'jun') {
    forestfireDf$month[i] = as.character(6)
       } else if (forestfireDf$month[i] == 'jul') {
    forestfireDf$month[i] = as.character(7)
       } else if (forestfireDf$month[i] == 'aug') {
    forestfireDf$month[i] = as.character(8)
       } else if (forestfireDf$month[i] == 'sep') {
    forestfireDf$month[i] = as.character(9)
       } else if (forestfireDf$month[i] == 'oct') {
    forestfireDf$month[i] = as.character(10)
       } else if (forestfireDf$month[i] == 'nov') {
    forestfireDf$month[i] = as.character(11)
       } else if (forestfireDf$month[i] == 'dec') {
    forestfireDf$month[i] = as.character(12)}
}
```

Comment: I think you don't need `data.frame(cbind` as the `read.csv` is already a data.frame.  You can add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in read.csv to read as strings as character class instead of `factor`.  Also, to convert to index, you can use `mach(forestfires$month, month.abb)`

Comment: as a general tip you should really be using date libraries instead of copy paste code like this.

Comment: are you sure it's not a factor / string issue?

Comment: OK I removed the cbind. Thanks I am new to R.

Comment: @qwr I dont know whether its a factor / string issue but that could make sense.

Comment: Well by using stringsAsFactors = FALSE one of the months was converted, aug to 8. Just 1 of 500

Comment: @Thomas_  Not clear how you read it `read.csv('forestfires.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: @akrun yes thats correct. I added to stringsAsFactors = FALSE to read.csv

Comment: I wouldn't use the loop to do the conversion.  `match(forestfires$month, month.abb)` would be enough if the values are `Jan`, `Feb`, `Mar`

Comment: @akrun that just outputed NA for everything

Comment: it was because the `month.abb` is `Jan`, `Feb`, etc. and the values you have are `jan`, `feb`, .  convert to lower case for month.abb as in the solution below and it should work

Comment: It's hard to know what exactly is going on without the data. Why are you using `if`/`else` like this instead of the vectorized `ifelse`, at the very least? That would still be inefficient, but would fit the type of data better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier option would be

```
forestfires$month <- as.character(match(forestfires$month, tolower(month.abb)))
```

Comment: Yes that did it. Just one line. Amazing. Thank you very much!